# jQuery get next element for the attribute within Prototype framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, prototype

Hello all I am trying to get the second element in the following:

```
<div class="progress-button elastic">
    <button data-id="0" id="bob">
      <span>
         <img src="http://...../_thumb.png" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;padding-top: 1px;float: right;padding-right: 9px;" class="likeImg">
      </span>
    </button>
    <svg class="circle" width="70" height="70">
      <path d="m35,2.5c17.955803,0 32.5,14.544199 32.5,32.5c0,17.95580.........">
      </path>
    </svg>
    <svg class="check" width="70" height="70">
      <path d="m31.5,46.5l15.3,-23.2"></path>
      <path d="m31.5,46.5l-8.5,-7.1"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is getting the **data-id** attribute from the second element (that being the **button**)

However I am unable to get that using this code within the function that call some animation for that button:

```
UIProgressButton.prototype._submit = function() {
    classie.addClass( this.el, 'loading' );
    console.log(this.el);
    console.log($(this.el).next().attr('id'));

    var self = this,
        onEndBtnTransitionFn = function( ev ) {
            if( support.transitions ) {
                if( ev.propertyName !== 'width' ) return false;
                this.removeEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndBtnTransitionFn );
            }

            this.setAttribute( 'disabled', '' );

            if( typeof self.options.callback === 'function' ) {
                self.options.callback( self );
            } else {
                self.setProgress(1);
                self.stop();
            }
        };

    if( support.transitions ) {
        this.button.addEventListener( transEndEventName, onEndBtnTransitionFn );
    } else {
        onEndBtnTransitionFn();
    }
}
```

The **console.log(this.el);** shows up like the first code post above *(the HTML)*.

When it gets to the **console.log($(this.el).next().attr('id'));** part, it just says *undefined*.

If I put **console.log($(this.el).attr('class'));** then I *do* get a value of **progress-button elastic** as I would expect going to the **next()** would work also.

What all would I be missing in order to get that value?

Comment: The title says jQuery but I see no sign of it in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`next()` is trying to find the sibling of your div, not the first child (button) you are expecting.

You can instead use `this.el` as context, and select within it: `$(this.el).children(":first")` should give you the button

Comment: But I would not know the id... im trying to **find the id**. There are more buttons on the page that use the same javascript and I need to distinguish them from each other's click event.

Comment: Ah ok, your edit included what I was originally looking for **console.log($(":first-child", this.el).attr('id'));**

Comment: If you want the `data-id` then use `data()` instead of `attr()`. `console.log($(":first-child", this.el).data('id'));`

Comment: If you are trying to get the first child then it is neater to use `$(this.el).down()`.